# Disabling mouseover on text in raphael js

Tags: text, raphael, mouseover, set

I am just starting out with raphael js and I am kinda stuck here: http://jsfiddle.net/wC9hX/50/

I don't want the mouseover event to be active on the text label as it is causing the text to disappear/appear randomly. This question has already been asked and the suggested solution was to use sets.

I have tried using sets but it doesn't solve my problem. Please help me out! thanks!

This is how I am creating the sets:

```js
var group = paper.set();    
group.push(chevron);
group.push(text);
group.push(description);
```

This is the `mouseout` function:

```js
group.mouseout(function() {

    description.animate({
        opacity: 0
    }, 250, 'linear');


    chevron.animate({
        path: "M 5 250 l 200 25 l 200 -25 l 0 50 l -200 25 l -200 -25 z",
        fill: '#000'
    }, 500, 'linear');  

    text.animate({
        fill: '#fff'
    }, 500, 'linear');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove all shapes that should not trigger the animation from the group (only `chevron` should be retained).
2. Apply `stop()` before triggering new animation calls.

See the [updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wC9hX/67/).